# Cannot compile Cpp project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, file-not-found

-------------EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So after some playing around here's what I'm getting when trying to recompile after a clean:

```
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPKDArray.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPKDArray.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwWiGUi.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPKDArray.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o SPBPriorityQueue.o "..\\SPBPriorityQueue.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPBPriorityQueue.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPBPriorityQueue.c -quiet -dumpbase SPBPriorityQueue.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPBPriorityQueue.o -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZ63HTs.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPBPriorityQueue.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPBPriorityQueue.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZ63HTs.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPBPriorityQueue.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o SPPoint.o "..\\SPPoint.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPPoint.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPPoint.c -quiet -dumpbase SPPoint.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPPoint.o -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZKf2SI.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPPoint.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPPoint.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZKf2SI.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPPoint.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    g++ "-IC:\\Users\\Amit\\Desktop\\opencv\\build\\include" "-IC:\\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\\modules\\xfeatures2d\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -v -o SPImageProc.o "..\\SPImageProc.cpp" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=g++
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' 'C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include' '-I' 'C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++11' '-v' '-o' 'SPImageProc.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -I C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include -I C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPImageProc.cpp -quiet -dumpbase SPImageProc.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPImageProc.o -g3 -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\cctEWbmX.s
    GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++/mingw32"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++/backward"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include
     C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++/mingw32
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++/backward
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 5086496b116ea21cdc0e479568243b88
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' 'C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include' '-I' 'C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++11' '-v' '-o' 'SPImageProc.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -I C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include -I C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include -o SPImageProc.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\cctEWbmX.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' 'C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include' '-I' 'C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++11' '-v' '-o' 'SPImageProc.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o SPList.o "..\\SPList.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPList.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPList.c -quiet -dumpbase SPList.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPList.o -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHg9Psy.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPList.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPList.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHg9Psy.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPList.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o SPLogger.o "..\\SPLogger.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPLogger.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPLogger.c -quiet -dumpbase SPLogger.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPLogger.o -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpZWnnU.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPLogger.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPLogger.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpZWnnU.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPLogger.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o SPConfig.o "..\\SPConfig.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPConfig.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPConfig.c -quiet -dumpbase SPConfig.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPConfig.o -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccJnBt14.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPConfig.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPConfig.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccJnBt14.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPConfig.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o SPListElement.o "..\\SPListElement.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPListElement.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\SPListElement.c -quiet -dumpbase SPListElement.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip SPListElement.o -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\cccmQ0rd.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPListElement.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o SPListElement.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\cccmQ0rd.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Werror' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'SPListElement.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    gcc -O0 -g3 -Wextra -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -v -o MainFunctions.o "..\\MainFunctions.c" 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    Target: mingw32
    Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
    Thread model: win32
    gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wextra' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'MainFunctions.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/ -dD ..\MainFunctions.c -quiet -dumpbase MainFunctions.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase-strip MainFunctions.o -g3 -O0 -Wextra -std=c99 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI00owu.s
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed"
    ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include"
    ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../include
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include-fixed
     c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.3 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 32bccaa1a45d39107471fe656e1c3cd5
    ..\MainFunctions.c: In function 'getKNN':
    ..\MainFunctions.c:360:2: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
      return *similarImages;
      ^
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wextra' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'MainFunctions.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o MainFunctions.o C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccI00owu.s
    GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
    COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
    LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wextra' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c99' '-v' '-o' 'MainFunctions.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
    g++ "-LC:\\Users\\Amit\\Desktop\\opencv\\build\\x86\\mingw\\lib" -o Final.exe MainFunctions.o SPBPriorityQueue.o SPConfig.o SPImageProc.o SPKDArray.o SPKDTree.o SPList.o SPListElement.o SPLogger.o SPPoint.o main.o -llibopencv_core310 -llibopencv_imgcodecs310 -llibopencv_imgproc310 -llibopencv_xfeatures2d310 -llibopencv_features2d310 -llibopencv_highgui310 
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    11:57:34 Build Finished (took 5s.337ms)
```

Comment: probably you should explicitly specify executable in Eclipse

Comment: If you just build it, without running it, is your executable generated? Otherwise take a look at your build/debug configuration...

Comment: Make sure you are building the target you're running. For example, building the release target and trying to debug the debug target. If that's not the problem, clean the project and force a complete rebuild.

Comment: So i've deleted everything that was in the Debug folder and issued a "Build All" command but nothing occured. it says it cannot find any .o files